# Connecting to GoogleRefine using Java program

Tags: java, google-refine

This question is similar to the posting 'Script-driven automation of Google refine with ruby python perl java or otherwise': [Script-driven automation of Google refine with ruby python perl java or otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598510/script-driven-automation-of-google-refine-with-ruby-python-perl-java-or-otherwis/8658684#8658684)

I have a lengthy JSON Script that I created in GoogleRefine and I am using it to clean several individual text files. Currently, I need to load each file manually into GoogleRefine and run the JSON script.

Is there a Java code/library that I can use to connect to GoogleRefine and pass on my JSON script and text file locations in order to speedily clean all of my files? I don't know Python and since the post above is dated 2011, I am wondering if a Java libray/program has been written since then.

Answer (score 0):

Today there is no Java library. You can find them in following languages:

- [python](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-python)
- [ruby](https://github.com/maxogden/refine-ruby)
- [JavaScript](https://github.com/pm5/node-openrefine)

You can read more about the OpenRefine API here: https://github.com/OpenRefine/refine-python/wiki/Refine-API